# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

Here is simplified version of my code below which is generating following compilation error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

GetDataAsync method does not need to return anything in this case. How can I make it return a Task that I can wait on?

```
static async void Run()
{
    List<string> IDs = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
    Task[] tasks = new Task[IDs.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < IDs.Count; i++)
        tasks[i] = await GetDataAsync(IDs[i]);

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);    
}

async static Task GetDataAsync(string id)
{
    var data = await Task.Run(() => GetDataSynchronous(id));
    // some other logic to display data in ui
}
```

Comment: `GetDataAsync` is returning a task, however, `Run` is not.  `async void` should only be used for event handlers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are trying to store the results of all your calls to `GetDataAsync` which are tasks, you shouldn't be awaiting them. Simply remove the `await`, collect all the tasks and wait for them at the end.

```
static void Run()
{
    List<string> IDs = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
    Task[] tasks = new Task[IDs.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < IDs.Count; i++)
        tasks[i] = GetDataAsync(IDs[i]);

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);    
}
```

Also, there's no need to make `Run` async at all (especially not `async void` which should only be used for UI event handlers) since you are waiting synchronously with `Task.WaitAll`.

If you want to wait asynchronously then make `Run` `async void` (only if it's a UI event handler) and use `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` to wait all tasks together:

```
static async void Run()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(new[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}.Select(GetDataAsync));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of an async function is **Task** instead of void and Task`<TResult`> instead of TResult.

If you change your function into the following it will be correct:

```
private static async Task Run()
{
    ...
    await ...
}
```

> There is one exception, an async event handler may return void:

```
private async void OnButton1_clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    await Run();
}
```

This is enough to keep your UI responsive while the task is running.

- You can only use await in a function if your function is async
- async functions return Task instead of void and Task`<TResult`> instead of TResult.

  - the value of await Task`<TResult`>, is TResult.
  - only async functions can all other async functions.

If you have a non-async function and you want to start a task while doing other things, you can use the following code:

```
private void MyFunction()
{
    // do some processing
    // start a separate task, don't wait for it to finish:
    var myTask = Task.Run( () => MyAsyncFunction(...))
    // while the task is running you can do other things
    // after a while you need the result:
    TResult result = await myTask;
    ProcessResult(result);
}
```

You can even start several tasks, and while they are processing do other things and after a while wait for the tasks to finish:

```
private async void OnButton1_clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    var Tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        Tasks.Add(Run());
    }
    // while all tasks are scheduled to run, do other things
    // after a while you need the result:
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // Task.WhenAll(...) returns a Task, so await Task.WhenAll returns void
    // async functions that return Task`<TResult`> has a Result property 
    // that has the TResult value when the task if finished:
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        ProcessResult(task.Result);
    }
    // not valid for your Run(), because that had a Task return value.
}
```