# Cannot convert void to Task, when passing a delegate to a method with generic

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following method that accepts a delegate:

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteWithRetryAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> action)
        {
            try
            {
                return await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                {
                    return await action();
                });
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException)
            {
                return default(T);
                //log this to queue
            }
        }
```

Normally I call it this way and it works fine:

```
  var saleCheckResult = await ExecuteWithRetryAsync(async () => await _client.CheckSaleAsync(SaleId));
```

This is the delegate I am passing:

```
  public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SaleCheckResult> CheckSaleAsync(string saleId)
    {
        return CheckSaleAsync(saleId, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

Here is the problem, I have the following method I want to pass to the Execute with retry as a delegate:

```
 public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task DisableMachineAsync(string machineId)
    {
        return DisableMachineAsync(machineId, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

I am using the same logic to call it:

```
await ExecuteWithRetryAsync(async () => await _client.DisableMachineAsync(machineId));
```

I get the following error " type arguments for method cannot be inferred from usage try to specify arguments explicitly", I understand I should specify arguments, so I tried this since the delegate returns a Task

```
  await ExecuteWithRetryAsync<Task>(async () => await _client.DisableMachineAsync(machineId))
```

Now I get an error cannot implicitly convert void to Task, something I dont understand I cannot use void as a type argument so how can I make sure I pass the correct delegate. Why is it telling me that it wants to convert void to Task, the delegate is returning Task and also the ExecuteWithRetry, how can I make this compile. I found a similar post here but thats a bit different issue [Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005498/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-void-to-system-threading-tasks-task)

Comment: Because `Task` is not `Task<T>` it is the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an overload which will accept `Func<Task>`:

```
async Task ExecuteWithRetryAsync(Func<Task> action)
{
    try
    {
        await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
             await action();
        });
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        //log this to queue
    }
}
```

And let compiler select an overload based on the provided func.

> Why is it telling me that it wants to convert void to Task

Because this invocation `await ExecuteWithRetryAsync<Task>` requires return type of `Task<Task>`, while awaiting `Task` results in `void`.

Comment: thanks @Guru Stron, I did not notice it requires type of Task<Task>, this seems to works  await ExecuteWithRetryAsync(async() => await(Task<Task>)_client.DisableMachineAsync(machineId));  Would you recommend creating overload or is getting Task<Task> absolutely fine?